# How to add an optional parameter to a decorator in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, decorator, typescript1.8

I want to create a field decorator that optionally can take an argument.
The argument should contain any of the following values: nothing, a boolean or a function.
I know how to do this, but I'm not 100% happy with the result:

```
export class TestClass{

   @Required(isRequired) 
   public testField: string;

}

export function isRequired():boolean{
   ... some validation logic, maybe depending on other fields...
   return result;
}
```

Implementation of @Required:

```
export function Required(expression?: boolean|Function): Function {
    return (target: any, key: string) => {
        if (expression === null || typeof expression == 'undefined') {
            expression = true;
        }
        console.log("Required found: " + expression, ":", target, key);
        ... register the field and its validation expression for later usage
    }
}
```

So this works fine, but when I do not want to add an expression (and thus use the defaulted "true" expression) I want to be able to write it like this:

```
class TestClass{

   @Required
   public testField: string;

}
```

I get a TypeScript error (TS1240) saying:

> Unable to resolve signature of property decorator when called as an
>   expression.   Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call
>   target

So I need to write @Required()

```
class TestClass{

   @Required()
   public testField: string;

}
```

Is it possible to write a decorator implementation that takes optionally an argument and when that argument is not specified there is no need to add the "()" ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, it is possible.

Here is a working example:

```
export type Target = {
  new (...args: any[]): any,
  name: string
};

export function Component(target: Target): void;
export function Component(name: string): (target: Target) => void;
export function Component(nameOrTarget: string | Target) {
  if (typeof nameOrTarget !== 'string') {
    console.log(nameOrTarget.name, ' is now decorated');
  } else {
    return function (target: Target) {
      const name = nameOrTarget || target.name;
      console.log(name, ' is now decorated');
    };
  }
}

@Component
export class MyDatabase { }

@Component('Hello Db')
export class MyHelloDatabase { }
```

The most important part is the following two lines:

```
export function Component(target: Target): void;
export function Component(name: string): (target: Target) => void;
```

If anyone is looking for more information, check out this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13173).

Answer (score 2):

No, you probably can't do that.
The reason for that is that decorators have a specific signature (which varies depending on the type of the decorator).
If you use a decorator function then you don't need the brackets, but if you use [a decorator factory](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#decorator-factories) (like you do in your example) then you must call it using brackets.

What you can do is separating the two into two different functions:

```
function Required(target: any, key: string, expression?: boolean | Function) {
    if (expression === null || typeof expression == 'undefined') {
        expression = true;
    }
    console.log("Required found: " + expression, ":", target, key);
}

function RequiredWith(expression: boolean | Function): Function {
    return (target: any, key: string) => {
        return Required(target, key, expression);
    }
}
```

And then you can either:

```
class TestClass {
    @Required
    public testField: string;
}
```

Or:

```
class TestClass2 {
    @RequiredWith(true)
    public testField: string;
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20Required(target%3A%20any%2C%20key%3A%20string%2C%20expression%3F%3A%20boolean%20%7C%20Function)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(expression%20%3D%3D%3D%20null%20%7C%7C%20typeof%20expression%20%3D%3D%20'undefined')%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20expression%20%3D%20true%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(%22Required%20found%3A%20%22%20%2B%20expression%2C%20%22%3A%22%2C%20target%2C%20key)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20RequiredWith(expression%3A%20boolean%20%7C%20Function)%3A%20Function%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(target%3A%20any%2C%20key%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20Required(target%2C%20key%2C%20expression)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20TestClass%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%40Required%0A%20%20%20%20public%20testField%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20TestClass2%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%40RequiredWith(true)%0A%20%20%20%20public%20testField%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D))